# What crypto should be used in PHP for crypting passwords?

Tags: php, cryptography

Thinking about to write a PHP script storing passwords in a DB, what php-crypto-function should i use?
Hashing is not an option, cause the passwords have to be stored cryted and able to be encrypted, so the user can see them.

Comment: Try  using with mysql `AES_ENCRYPT` and `AES_DECRYPT` options if you are free to choose crypting techniques . This can be decrpyted and shown to users , if my understanding is right. If your must proceed with php take a look at mcrypt, but you need proper handling of mcrpyt since it contains binary data associated with it after encryption (well `AES_ENCRPYT` too)

Comment: Is the user aware that allowing their decrypted passwords to be visible by them is making their password less secure?

Comment: It is the core function for the user that he can store his password and is able to get it back in readable version. My question is, how to store them secure in between. Second, the tool is in use only "behind the firewall", in intranets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your product's code function is to allow the user to view passwords, symmetric encryption is what you want.

Check out the API docs for mcrypt (MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC)